# How to fix horizontal scrollbar caused by jQuery FlexSlider?

Tags: jquery, css, web, horizontal-scrolling, flexslider

jQuery FlexSlider is causing horizontal scrollbar here: http://abhinavsood.com/labs/grab/
I have tried `overflow-x: hidden` on flex-container but it doesn't seem to solve it.

Can anyone take a look and suggest a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
background-position: 100% 0;
right: -36px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
left: -36px;
}
```

remove the `left` and `right -36px`, I don't see any arrows on your page so probably you can remove those elemnts inside `flex-direction-nav` div

Comment: if you don't need them you can set directionNav: false, in scripts.js at line 27 and this should properly disable the arrows,

Comment: I also got reminded of directionNav after reading your answer. Thanks @magnum2002 :)

Answer (score 9):

It is actually your `.flex-direction-nav .flex-next` anchor that is causing it.

I fixed it by applying `right: 0;` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by edit the following 2 things:

line 329 at style.css add

```
overflow:hidden !important;

.flexslider .slides > li {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

and at 372 to 385

```
bottom:10px; left: 10px;overflow: hidden;

.flexslider.position-caption-bottom-left .flex-caption{
bottom:10px;
left: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align:left;

}
.flexslider.position-caption-bottom-right .flex-caption {
bottom:10px;
left: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align:right;
}
.flexslider.position-caption-bottom-centered .flex-caption {
bottom:10px;
left: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way I managed to fix this is I added in options:

```
useCSS: false
```

for example:

```
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    useCSS: false
  });
```

Because when it is set to true the element ul.slides becomes 1000% wide and causes browser to make horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
left: 0 !important;}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
right: 0 !important;}
```

Worked for me! ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Wİth some tweaking, this is the closest solution to problem. Unfortunately, this causes because of the navigation arrows that have been hidden with the right and left css rules. But of course this answer should be updated to reflect what should be done and where to place this code etc.